# What is populate in SailsJs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I recently began to develop on sailsJs and not understanding the subtleties
Please explain to me what is populate in SailsJs and who can please do simple example
Thanks in advance ?
whats is ?

```
User.find({ name: 'foo' })
.populate('pets', { name: 'fluffy' })
.exec(function(err, users) {
  if(err) return res.serverError(err);
  res.json(users);
});
```

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Sails uses waterline as the default ORM. And waterline also supports associations, although the feature exists in mongoose from quite a long time.

Comment: If the answer below satisfies your question, then it is recommended and also a good practice to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It's also pretty good practice to [read the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/populate.html).

Answer (score 5):

populate is used for associations. When your model is something like this:

```
// User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: "string"
    },

    pet: {
      model: "pet"
    }

  }
}
```

Here pet attribute of user collection is a reference to pet table. In user table it will store only the id column of pet. However, when you do a populate while find, then it will fetch the entire record of the pet entry and display it here. This is just for one to one association. You can have many to one associations as well as many to many. See this [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations) for more details

Answer (score 0):

sailsjs project is use the [wateline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs) ORM. you can see the document. if you want to use 'populate()', you need define Associations in the model.

#### .populate()

populate is used with associations to include any related values specified in a model definition. If a collection attribute is defined in a many-to-many, one-to-many or many-to-many-through association the populate option also accepts a full criteria object. This allows you to filter associations and run limit and skip on the results.

as you example, you need do like this:

### User.js

```js
// A user may have many pets
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'user',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',

    // Add a reference to Pets
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
});
```

#### Pet.js

```js
// A pet may only belong to a single user
var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'pet',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    breed: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',

    // Add a reference to User
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
});
```

you can ready the doc, and you can use it very easy

Answer (score 0):

To resume what is **.populate()** (used by waterline) is a little what **join** is used by SQL.

**.populate()** allows you to join the tables in your database.
The link identifier is to be defined in your model.

In other words, to associate a user (who is in the "User" table) with a dog (who is in the "Dog" table), you use populate.

To resume your example:

You are looking for the user => *User.find ({name: my_user})*
You are looking for the dog named "fluffy" => *{name: 'fluffy'}*
You are looking for the dog 'fluffy' which is associated with your user (belongs) => *populate ('pets')*

Which give:

```
User.find({ name: 'foo' })
.populate('pets', { name: 'fluffy' })
.exec(function(err, users) {
 if(err) return res.serverError(err);
 res.json(users);
}
```

This association ("pets"), you define it in your models "User" and "Pets" like the example above.

Answer (score -5):

Populate is all about displaying the content of the (id) on which it was refreed

```
"abc": [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "xyz"
}],
```